# JavaFx won't schange Scenes

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

```
package Data_Project;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {
    public Stage window;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        window = primaryStage;
        //Scene1
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Parent root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Admin.fxml"));
        Controller a1 = new Controller();
        a1.getSubmitButton().setOnAction(e -> {
            window.setScene(new Scene(root1,500,500));
        });
        window.setTitle("Log in");
        window.setScene(new Scene(root,500,500));
        window.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       launch(args);

    }
}
```

Hey there, im getting error with this code, I can't figure out what's wrong.

> Exception in Application start method Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$1/989110044.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   Data_Project.Main.start(Main.java:20)

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Data_Project.Controller">
   <children>

          <Label text="Username" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
          <TextField fx:id="userField" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
          <Label text="Password" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
          <PasswordField fx:id="passField" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
          <Button fx:id="submitButton" onAction="#submitForm" text="Log in" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
          <Label fx:id="errorLabel" textFill="#c30808" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
   </children>

</GridPane>






<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Data_Project.Admin">
    <children>

        <Label text="Username" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <TextField fx:id="userField" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <Label text="Password" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <PasswordField fx:id="passField" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <Button fx:id="submitButton" text="Log in" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
        <Label fx:id="errorLabel" textFill="#c30808" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
    </children>

</GridPane>
```

The XML are both Different Files, but shown here as 1 file, they have the same attributes and all because it was for testing the scene switcher, but for some reason i can't get it to work!

Controller class:

```
package Data_Project;


import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;


public class Controller{
    Scene window;
    @FXML Button submitButton;
    @FXML TextField userField;
    @FXML PasswordField passField;
    @FXML Label errorLabel;

    public void submitForm(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
       authorizedUser user = new authorizedUser();
        if(!user.checkCredentials(userField.getText(), passField.getText()))
        {
            errorLabel.setText("Invalid credentials");
        }
    }


    public Button getSubmitButton() {
        return submitButton;
    }
}
```

Admin:

```
package Data_Project;


import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;


public class Admin{
    Scene window;
    @FXML Button submitButton;
    @FXML TextField userField;
    @FXML PasswordField passField;
    @FXML Label errorLabel;

    public Button getSubmitButton() {
        return submitButton;
    }
}
```

Comment: Done, the post is edited now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FXMLLoader` parses the FXML file, creates an instance of the controller class (if one is specified) and injects any `@FXML`-annotated fields into that controller instance.

If you create your own controller instance, as you do with

```
Controller a1 = new Controller();
```

then the `FXMLLoader` knows nothing of that instance (how would it?) and so the `@FXML`-annotated fields are not initialized. Hence when you call

```
a1.getSubmitButton()
```

it returns `null` and so you get a `NullPointerException`.

To fix this, replace

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
```

and

```
Controller a1 = new Controller();
```

with

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
Controller a1 = loader.getController();
```

This gives you a reference to the controller instance *that the `FXMLLoader` created*, so it has its `@FXML`-annotated fields properly initialized.